# Passing query parameters to vue components through the router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Im trying to start my app with a sample url like this one : https://www.example.com/?foo=bar

I tried the following in my Vue Router as explained here (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode)  :

```
function dynamicPropsFn (route) {
  console.log(route.query.foo) // undefined ??
  return {
    foo: route.query.foo
  }
}

//...
{
  path: "/",
  name: "landing",
  meta : {layout : 'landing'},
  component : Landing,
  props: dynamicPropsFn
},//...
```

My issue is that the query string parameter is always undefined ...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the plunker with your function and its working fine for me.

```
[https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moePxK]
```

The function is executed when the user clicks on the router.

Comment: I was missing the "  mode:'history' " in my Router, thanks for your help !